# php display an alert box if a field in a form is not entered

Tags: javascript, php

I want to detect if a condition is met in php and if not show a javascript alert box and prevent the form from processing

I tried to set up the alert box but it always runs

```
function confirmfillin()
{
    $pm = $SQL->query("SELECT * FROM `".TABLE_PREFIX."shopping` WHERE user_id='".$userdata['id']."' AND shopping_id='".$store['id']."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($pm)<1) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('fill in form');</script>";
    }
}
?>

<form action=postfinish.php method=POST>
<input name="title" type="text" value="my title" >

<div style="position:fixed; bottom:4in; right:20;"><input type="submit" class="submitter" onClick=<?php confirmfillin(); ?> value="Select your item and submit" style="width:220px;"></div>
</form>
```

the alert show each time the page loads

Comment: `mysql_num_rows` REALLY?? Are you really using the `mysql_` API? Did you connect using the `mysql_Connect()`??

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: PS: You cannot run a PHP function from the HTML that has been delivered to the browser. You can only run jsvascript in the browser, PHP runs on the server

Comment: You assumed that the php function is called onClick of submit button in browser but in reality it is called the moment the page is rendered, hence the alert on every load. You are mixing client-side and server-side scripts.

Comment: Is there any way to get this to operate as expected or should I just use jquery?